# AdMob Integration Confustion: How do I create AdFragment and AdFragment object?

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

I am publishing my first Android App, and I would like to put an AdMob ad unit in it. I am very new to java, and coding in general.

I am using this guide: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#faq

I get stuck on "Create the AdFragment object", the instructions get a little vague there. Can anyone clarify what I need to do?

Thanks!